# 500 Failure error using Linkedin post inspector

Tags: linkedin-api

I added meta tags for LinkedIn post share:

```html
<html>

<head id="meta-tags">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Title">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Company Name">
    <meta property="og:description">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.jpg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="682">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="682">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
</head>

</html>
```

It works perfectly using Ngrok with my local environment. But, as soon as I deploy it to Azure's App Service with a GoDaddy SSL certificate it stopped working.

[image]

[image]

Facebook and Twitter crawler works as usual. The only problem is with Linkedin: I read somewhere that it could be related to SSL trust issue but I don't know how to test that.

Comment: Hi @jose Did you able to find the issue ?

Comment: @SandunTharaka It was probably a trust issue between LinkedIn and my SSL certificates, but I could not prove it, and the support from LinkedIn was zero. In the end, we removed that feature